# How to add subcategories in woo commerce product csv upload?

Tags: csv, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am trying to upload books to my Woo Commerce site and need to have multiple subcategories per product.  When I upload the CSV with categories (Parent > Subcategory 1 > Subcategory 2) they don't show up with the product.  They create the 1st sub in the categories list under the parent but not on the product.  And the 2nd tier of subcategories doesn't show up at all.  I've also tried (parent>subcategory1>>subcatagory2) and still no luck... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a product has multiple categories or sub-categories, they need to be seperated with '|' in the CSV, for example:

```
Parent | Parent > Subcategory 1 | Parent > Subcategory 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, or what results you're getting.

If you want a product to be in all three of those categories AND sub-categories, you need to import it as:

`Parent, Parent > Subcategory 1, Parent > Subcategory 1 > Subcategory 2`

if you just do:

`Parent > Subcategory 1 > Subcategory 2`

then the product will *only* be put in Subcategory 2

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I figured that out after a lot of trial and error and exporting/importing products. That is exactly what I was looking for.  I was missing the parent for every subcategory.  Thank you!